# How to install C# language support in Atom

Tags: programming-languages, syntax-highlighting, atom-editor

I've just started using https://atom.io/ on OSX

If I open a C# file it doesn't syntax highlight.

I've found https://github.com/atom/language-csharp

Do I just clone that and copy it into /Applications/Atom.app/Contents/Resources/app/node_modules ?

Answer (score 38, accepted):

Go into preferences -> Packages and type 'CSharp'

[image]

I've used Lisp in the picture as I already installed CSharp so it won't show up any more.

Comment: @P i can I compile c# from atom if I install this package?

Comment: My company has proxy server to go to Internet, it does not seems that Atom uses the system proxy at all, thus all the packages are not searchable from inside the tool. Is there a way I can download and apply to the tool?

Comment: For future reference, run atom or apm with proxychains. Should work

Answer (score 15):

If you've installed the command line utilities, you can also "apm install language-csharp" from the command line.

Answer (score 9):

Omnisharp is recommended for C# support in Atom. Here's the package installation commands from their page.

```
apm install language-csharp
apm install autocomplete-plus
apm install omnisharp-atom
```

https://atom.io/packages/omnisharp-atom

Answer (score 3):

This was added to the core packages in February 2015, so if you're running the latest version of Atom it should be already installed.

Here's the pull request: https://github.com/atom/atom/pull/5408

Answer (score 1):

1. File > Settings > Install
   (Or on MacOS: Atom > Preferences > Install)
2. Search for "language-csharp"